# posting data on jquery change effect

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using jquery with ci framework and I want to post data on change  event.my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txta').live('change',function(){
        var sr=$('#txta').val();
        var qid = $("#txta").attr("qaid");
        // alert(sr+'Q:no'+qid)
        $.get('<?php echo base_url()?>testpapers/responseText()',{},
            function(data){
            $('#res').html(data)
            });             
    });
});
```

when I use alert function which is commented here I get the value but when I pass  data to div id="res" then I get nothing

my function is

```
function responseText(){
    echo "working ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using get method which is used to send data not to get back any data. For this purpose you should use either ajax method or deffered object.

Study this object The jqXHR Object

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
And ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rab Nawaz that this code is not sending any parameters to the server. But as I see the server function, I believe you are first trying to test the jQuery get method and then write more code.

I can see a mistake there:

In this line

```
$.get('<?php echo base_url()?>testpapers/responseText()',{}, function(data){
```

remove `()` from `responseText()` and you code will work.

This `()` leads to a 404 error and you are not getting back any data as the ajax call is not successful. The easy way to debug this should be to use firebug to see the response / error for each request to the server.